# Creating a new user via Firebase Cloud Functions - account created but can not sign in

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I am new here.

I am currently developing an app using Vue.js with firebase auth, firebase realtime database and firebase cloud functions as a backend. One part of the functionalities that the app has to include an admin account that has a possibility to create an accounts for other people. After creation new user receives an email with a login and a password to log in.

Because the signing up method (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) automatically relog user to a newly created account which is obviously not wanted behavior I found a way to create a user via cloud functions. The code successfully creates an account in the firebase authentication panel with the exception that I cannot log in to the newly created accounts. I get a message that: "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password".

Additionally I am not sure if it means anything in this case but the accounts created with the cloud functions method does not have a mail icon in firebase authentication panel ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jlE6.jpg)).

**Cloud Function Code:**

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
console.log(data)
return admin.auth().createUser({
    email: data.email,
    emailVerified: true,
    password: data.password,
    displayName: data.email,
    disabled: false,
  })
    .then(user => {
        return {
            response: user
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed to create a user')
    });
```

});

**Sign In Code:**

```
signIn: async function(){
  if(this.email && this.password){

    let getUsers = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getUsers')

    this.feedback = null
    this.spin = true

    let destination = null
    let logedUser = null
    let type = null

    this.feedback = 'Logging in...'

    await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
      .then(response => {
        this.feedback = 'Authorization finished...'
        logedUser = response.user
      })
      .catch( error => {
        this.feedback = error.message
        this.spin = false
      })
//... more code here but I am certain it has nothing to do with the problem.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the asynchronous character of the HTTPS callable function, with your current code you are trying to sign-in **before** the user is completely created through the Cloud Function.

In addition, you are actually not calling the Cloud Function with the `mail` and `password` parameters.

You should do as follows, based on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function).

```
....
let getUsers = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getUsers')

await getUsers({email: this.email, password: this.password})
  .then(result => {
      return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
  })
  .then(userCredential => {
    this.feedback = 'Authorization finished...'
    logedUser = userCredential.user
    return true
  })
  .catch( error => {
    this.feedback = error.message
    this.spin = false
  })
....
```